# package configurations vs project configurations

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, package

I am wondering what considerations can lead to choosing package-configurations over project-configurations (or vice-versa) on Sql Server 2012.

I for example was told that using package-configurations it was easier to migrate ETL's from one machine to another.

edit: the question is about package configurations vs project configurations, not about package-parameters vs project parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is nothing that package-configuration can do which Project-configuration cannot do. The opposite is true however.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple packages in the same project are going to share the same parameter, and you want to be able to change it once and have that change affect all packages, you would make it a project parameter.

If only one package should use it, and you should be able to change it without affecting other packages in the same project, then you should make it a package parameter.

This is the only factor I consider when deciding.

Comment: That is both possible with project-configurations, But when to use package deployment model vs project deployment model?

Comment: We use project deployment model period.   I can't imagine any circumstance under which I would want to use package deployment model.

Comment: To be honest, same here. Am mainly wondering if there is something that I am overlooking. I cannot really think of a reason to stick with package-configuratiuons, still these people do. Even more, they developed their solution using package configurations when project deployment was already available.

Comment: Some people are so averse to learning anything new that they would rather let progress leave them behind.